# Cannot print correct values in Bison code

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer

So I'm trying to declare the syntax of an array (using Bison 3.6.2) as follows:

```
array: '[' array_vals ']'

array_vals:
| vals array_vals

vals: STRING //String values defined in my lexer
| FLOAT //Float values defined in my lexer
| INT //Integer values defined in my lexer
```

I feel like this is pretty self explanatory, but there's just one problem: Wherever I print the `array_vals`, using this: `array: '[' array_vals ']' { cout << $2 << endl; }` I get only the first value of the array in my source code, so if I have this in my source file: `[10, 20, 30, 40]` then it only prints `10`. I've tried printing the `vals` in `array_vals`, and it's even weirder and inconsistent. I know that this isn't a bug since I went from Bison version 3.5.1 to 3.6.2 and there was no difference. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your definition of array only allows one value, (and doesn't allow commas either) so I'm not sure how you even get your input to parse.

Comment: also, put `;` after the last rule: `A: decs | stmts | whatever ;`

Comment: @OrenIshShalom: why?

Comment: @john I edited it... now there can be more than one value. I wrote it down instead of copying and pasting so I accidentally missed it. Sorry!

Comment: This was needed in earlier versions, and also needed by other parser generators if you every switch to `jflex+CUP` for example

Comment: :@InfinitiStudios It still doesn't allow commas. But in any case I think the thing that is really needed is the C++ code that is invoked by `{ cout << $2 << endl; }`. Can't really debug code without seeing the code.

Comment: @john for this example I don't need commas; spaces will do the job, and I don't have and c++ code other than what's in those curly braces and a couple of header files

Comment: specifically iostream

Comment: a minor naming suggestion: since parsers usually involve lists of <something>'s, use `vals: val | val vals ;` rather than `array_vals`

Comment: @InfinitiStudios So you haven't give a type to your tokens and non-terminals? How are you gathering the array values?

Answer (score 1):

A general `flex+bison` advice: make them print **everything** they do.
So the lexer would have lines like this:

```
">=" { cout << ">= on line: " << line << "\n"; return parser::make_GEQ(loc); }
```

And the parser will have lines like this:

```
vals:
val      { cout << "vals -> val\n";      $$ = {$1};                  } |
val vals { cout << "vals -> val vals\n"; $2.push_front($1); $$ = $2; } ;
```

Comment: OKAY can you explain something to me? What does that $$ mean and how does that help me in this scenario?

Comment: there are two cases for using a parser: the first will take an input file and decide whether its content follows the grammar specified. the other will build an AST for later phases after the parser. $$ is used to automatically build such an AST.

Comment: do you have discord? Would you want to talk using that?